# Installing Spark on ec2 gives error EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I was following [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) guide for installing spark on ec2.But getting following error while launching cluster:

```
ERROR:boto:403 Forbidden
```

Comment: You're probably using incorrect AWS keys, or you haven't granted your AWS keys the right permissions.

Comment: For ec2 can we directly run Master and Worker using spark-class executable instaed of using spark-ec2 @NickChammas

Comment: I'm not sure. To date I've only ever launched and accessed Spark clusters on EC2 using `spark-ec2`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and got around it by using a "-w 600", which basically says wait for 600 second.  Apparently, there is some housekeeping that the process needs more time on.

Comment: Since 1.2.0, Spark deprecates the `-w` flag and automatically waits for the instances to be  on an `SSH-ready` state without having to specify a *waiting time*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out [here](http://neuralfoundry.com/spinning-up-a-spark-cluster-on-aws-ec2-step-by-step/) that you have to set the privilege of the user (the user from which you got your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) to the value **AmazonEC2FullAccess**

This should solve your problem for most of you !